# Cannot get HTTP call response while debugging but it exists on the browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, rxjs

I simply send an HTTP request to create a record and then get the added record id on the Network section of browsers that I tried Chrome, Firefox, but interestingly, I cannot get the same id value while debugging. Here is the code and the breakpoint that I am trying to get the response. I also tried to use `promise`, etc, but while it is working on other PC, I cannot get it on my PC (I also close antivirus app, etc. and clean browser histor, restart PC, restart the app, etc. But none of them make any sense.

```
this.myservice.create(<Employee>{ name: data.name, surname: data.surname })
  .pipe(
    tap((result) => {
      // --> I am expecting to get result as id value as it 
      // is seen on the Network tab of Google Developer tool
...
```

Note that my service returns an observable and there is no problem at that sied. The problem is most probably related to browser or pc settings e.g. firewall or etc.

Comment: can you share your http reponse by copying from network tab.

Comment: There is just a single id number of the created record e.g. 101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might depend on the implementation of `this.myservice.create`. If that is implemented eager instead of lazy that will mean that your http request is already invoked before you subscribe, effectively already giving you the http response in the network inspector. But it will only get into the `tap()` as an emission once you `subscribe()` to your Observable which makes the whole stream active.

Example 'lazy' implementation:

```
create() {
  return Observable.Create((obs) => {
    fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
      .then(response => {
        obs.onNext(response.json()); 
        obs.onCompleted();
      });
  });
}
```

This will invoke the `fetch` only once the observable is subscribed to.

Example of an eager implementation:

```
create(){
  const obs = new Rx.Subject();
  fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
    .then(response => {
      obs.next(response.json());
      obs.complete();
    });
  return obs;
}
```

This will start the fetch even though the observable is not subscribed to already. It might even lead to a race condition (the value is already pushed before being subscribed to).

Having 'eager' observables is in my opinion often a mistake // anti-pattern because it can lead to very confusing results unless the engineers know intimately how the system works and it is documented throughly. And then still....

Comment: Thnaks a lot, voted up. I think that is the exact cause. But how can I decide if my implementation of this.myservice.create is eager or lazy? My service method returns observable like that: `create(...): Observable<number> { ... }`

Comment: i've expanded my answer with an example